# In a controlled React number input, how can you trim leading zeros?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, controlled-component

In the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) it says that in a controlled component, "the React state be the “single source of truth”". This seems to be true except in cases with leading zeros. In the below example, you can see that the input is controlled, but in a case with leading zeros, the input value doesn't always match the state value.

---

**The Test**

Type leading zeros, so the value is something like `0010`.

You can see that the value in `state` is an integer `10`, but the input shows `0010`.

My first thought was this was because the component doesn't actually re-render, which is true. There's no state change between `10` and `10`, so no new render. This is confirmed since we don't see the 'render' console.log firing.

So let's make sure we change the value. Add a `2` to change `0010` to `00102`. The value in state is now `102`, we confirm the component re-renders...but still the leading zeros persist in the input.

---

This seems inconsistent as I would expect the value in the input to always match the value in state exactly. Why is this and what is a reliable way to trim leading zeros from a number input?

```js
// LEADING ZEROS INPUT TEST
// Step 1: type 0s into the input followed by any other digits
// Step 2: see that console log and val in `p` do not have leading 0's and input val does

const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(10);
  
  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const strVal = evt.currentTarget.value;
    console.log('string', strVal, typeof strVal);
    const intVal = parseInt(strVal, 10) || 0; // || 0 bc '' returns NaN
    console.log('int', intVal, typeof intVal);
    setVal(intVal);
  }
  
  console.log('render', val);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{val}</p>
      <input 
        type="number"
        value={val}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My wild guess is because inputs are strings, not integers, so it gets confused. E.g., if you keep `val` as a string, and convert it to a string after parsing/before `setVal`, it works (roughly) as expected, except for a wonky UX--which makes me thing that this kind of processing is best done later rather than on every key, since at least in Chrome it bounces the cursor to the end of the input if you enter a leading 0.

Comment: As a sidenote. This code works as intended with classical `this.state/this.setState`.

Comment: Actually, this has been going on since a while with both sides of the debate making sense - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9402

Comment: @jaybhatt Ahhh. I was close, but wrong with why :)

Comment: Tried to host a codepen to show how difficult this will be in terms of UX -https://codepen.io/jaybhatt21/pen/LYWZvbO.
Like it removes trailing zero, but a very confusing experience.

Comment: @jaybhatt That's what I did too, but it's pretty awful UX.

Comment: Yeah, probably the only good way maybe to have it as `text` maybe.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the thought. Since in my real world use case I'm doing things like validating and limiting (min/max) the value, switching it to an integer and then back to a string before setting state just seems cumbersome.

Comment: @sallf It is. However: leading zeros don't affect validation or limits; they're just noise. I don't see a compelling reason to remove them at all, especially given the UX issues caused by the component re-render.

Comment: @DaveNewton agreed, there's a good case to be made for "who cares, get over it" :). I guess what I'm more curious about is why is the input value different from the state value. I'm reading through the issue jaybhatt posted to see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: @sallf It's (er sort of) what I was saying, but for additional reasons, and changing that behavior leads to a significantly *worse* UX even than what I was seeing in my PoC, particularly for different varieties of floats. Another thing you *could* do is drop keyboard events when it's a 0 in the front--but I *really* wouldn't do that because it's just confusing.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton if the user wants to put a freaking zero in front, why not? you can always show an error message "wrong input format" instead of messing with user interaction, is too intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already aware of the **WHY** I'm going to help you with the **HOW**.

In my humble opinion a reliable way to trim leading zeros from a number input would be "on blur", this is less intrusive and provides a better user experience.

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(10);
  const [strVal, setStrVal] = useState("10"); // To keep a reference of the real input value
  
  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const inputVal = evt.currentTarget.value;
    setStrVal(inputVal);
    setVal(parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value, 10) || 0);
  }

  const handleBlur = useCallback((evt) => {
    setStrVal(val.toString());
  }, [val]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{val}</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={strVal}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but is not what is OP asking for at all :) if you want to avoid user entering certain characters and we all would agree leading zeros for numeric input certainly are, especially e.g. if you want to allow positive intergers only, thus you need to filter what characters are entered